# Page Server Error in '\' application

Tags: asp.net

On my local machine it's working but it's not working on server

error is showing like this

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'asp:Chart'.

Source Error:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213159/asp-chart-errors

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config  section add the following:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add tagPrefix="asp"
                 namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
                 assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/> 
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the assembly is installed on the server, and check if your web.config on the server includes the control assembly and namespace in the `<controls>` section.

For instance

```
<add tagPrefix="asp"
         namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
         assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

Check this link for more details, charts for MSDN - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh297118(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh297118%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:
 just to remove the following entry from web.config  section:

```
<httpHandlers>
<add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler,
    System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Also make sure that  section has the following:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
    <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler,
        System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</handlers>
```